# Design of fact table(s) and dimensions tables for data warehouse

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, facttable, olap

Hi i'm newbie in Datawarehousing, how would you model this in a Data Warehouse:

i wish design the Data Warehouse which  give the answers of statistics relating to a baseball league

For players

in offensive:

> •How many times has a batter to bat.
>
> •How many runs scored is.
>
> •How many hits,doubles hit and triples hits.
>
> •How many homeruns did.
>
> •many  RBI.
>
> •many base on balls

in Defensive:

> ▪ How many outs, double play takes
>
> ▪ How many assists has
>
> ▪ How many errors lead or Pitcher:
>
> ▪ How many games has lost
>
> ▪ has won many games
>
> ▪ How many saved games
>
> ▪ How many complete games leads
>
> ▪ How many games have started many
> times it has bleaching
>
> ▪ How many hit, double hit received, received triple hit, received homerun

It is important to check the equipment-specific information, this information is:

> • How many games won as a visitor and
> as homeclub
>
> • Games lost as a visitor
>
> • Games lost as a homeclub
>
> • How many times lost/gained when
> rival starting pitcher was left-handed
>
> • How many times lost/gained when
> rival starting pitcher was
> right-handed
>
> • How many games won / lost in extra
> inning

Additionally it is important to check the information of each of the games, this
information is:

> • Which team was homeclub
>
> • Which team was visiting
>
> • On what date was played
>
> • In what city was played
>
> • What was the score (it is a string of the form AB where A is the amount
> of runs scored by the winning team and losing team B)
>
> • The winning team
>
> • What pitcher lost
>
> • What pitcher won
>
> • What pitcher saved
>
> • Number season game

Other important highlights

> • Must be able to view detailed
> information for each player (name,
> Arm, etc).
>
> • Must be able to view detailed information for each team (Name, Headquarters, etc).
>
> • A season has 3 stages or Heat, or  RoundRobin or Final Round
>
> • It is important to know at-bat hitting a player, this shift comes from the alignment (first base, second  base, etc)
>
> • It is important to know the alignment of each play in defensive

As for the data of the players, it is important that this can be viewed as
season, as each inning game even as regards data equipos.En equipment is important that this can be viewed as
season.

Does anyone know some references on that precise part of DW design ? Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What has led you to think any sort of OLAP is necessary? How many players/games do you anticipate tracking with this database?

Comment: How many players/games do you anticipate tracking with this database?: i dont understand your question but, for player, games, and team the information can be viewed by season.

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Redbooks have a couple of good titles on modeling a data warehouse.

- [Data Modeling Techniques for Data
  Warehousing](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg242238.html?Open)
- [Dimensional Modeling: In a Business
  Intelligence Environment](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247138.html?Open)

You might be better served with an OLTP database in 5NF, though. It's not hard to test simplified versions of both.